# WPF select item in a scroll viewer

Tags: c#, wpf, image, scrollviewer, stackpanel

I have a `ScrollViewer` with a `StackPanel` that contains images. Is it possible to select items in the ScrollViewer/StackPanel?

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="Gallery" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="0"   
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
    <StackPanel x:Name="GalleryStack"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How exactly? why not use a Listbox?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [Image.BringIntoView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.bringintoview.aspx) method to bring them into the view. But as Elad points out, what you have doesn't really implement "selection" by itself. You could handle the MouseDown event of the Image elements and call the BringIntoView method.